# Error Loading WSDL in SOAP UI

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I am getting this error while loading a WSDL to SOAP UI.[SCREEN SHOT OF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAxjJ.png)

Comment: Please include the source code and the contents of the WSDL file

Comment: Are you able to open wsdl in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WSDL file is malformed, best way to find out what is wrong with it is to run it through some WSDL validation tool, like:

- built in Eclipse WSDL validation tool
- https://www.w3.org/wiki/WsdlValidator
- https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/
- ...

Disclaimer, I have not used any of this except for the Eclipse one, so proceed at your own risk.